# How to use DPAPI in c# winForms 4.0 for windows 7?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a c# applications that one acts as an add-in and other is an exe that sits in the system tray.

Each of these application has a login form that takes the company's user name and password(password expires for 30 days and also can be reset-ted). When I try to open the application independently, each application asks for the login credentials.
Say if I open application 'A' , then application 'A' asks for credentials and if i open application 'B', then that application also asks for the login credentials.

So now what I aiming is two applications should be activated on signing a single login form. That is single sign on should be able to log in two applications. 
In one of the forums I read the implementation of "DPAPI" could solve this issue. Not sure in the first place if this solution could resolve the issue. Please share your suggestions.

Comment: What exactly is DPAPI? The DPAPI that is found by googling it seems to be about encryption.

Comment: @nvoigt - yes its about encryption also but I just read it is used for single sign on for two applications to have a single login module. No idea on how far this is the solution. Looking for the best suggestions to solve this(or not).